# Automatically filling colors as per the values in the cell in spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

**Question :** Is it possible to fill each cell in a spreadsheet with a color whose grayscale value is same as cell value?

**Explanation :**

Consider I have a spreadsheet as follows :

[image]

All values lie between 0-255 ( which corresponds to 256 grayscale colors). Now I want to fill will each cell with the color whose value is the value in the cell. So expected output is as follows :

[image]

Also, see that font color in each cell is either black or white corresponding to the background color.

Is there any simple method in Excel to perform this in a very few steps or all at once ?

Comment: ok, it is possible to do this with conditional-formats, but if there is the possibility, you should use a macro for it.

Answer (score 5):

Create a Macro that iterates through your cells, reads the value in the cell and assigns it to the color like this:

```
Range("A1:A6").Interior.Color = RGB(200,160,35)
```

Answer (score 3):

TheUser1024 is right, and has my vote.

Here is a ready to use solution:

```
Public Sub Demo()
  Dim cel As Range
  Dim myRange As Range

  Set myRange = Range("A1:E10")

  For Each cel In myRange
    cel.Interior.Color = RGB(cel.Value, cel.Value, cel.Value)
    If cel.Value > 127 Then
      cel.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Else
      cel.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
  Next cel
End Sub
```

*Edit:*

This code won't break in case of strings or negative values ...

```
Public Sub Demo()
  Dim cel As Range
  Dim greytone As Long
  Dim myRange As Range

  Set myRange = Range("A1:E10")

  For Each cel In myRange
    greytone = CLng(Abs(Val(cel.Value)))
    cel.Interior.Color = RGB(greytone, greytone, greytone)
    If greytone > 127 Then
      cel.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Else
      cel.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
  Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: This works if all cells contain integers from 1 to 256, but it will throw an error for anything else.  You can add a condition in the for loop to check for this, and that should remove any error issues.

Comment: @Excellll yes, you're right - but it works for empty cells and all positive double values. However, I edited it to a more robust version, thanks for the hint!

Comment: I believe this deserves more upvoting than my answer, since it does all the fine detail. Mine just states the basic principle and i did not even think of that font.color aspect.